# How do I start a chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

How do I open a chat room in chat? Do I need more reputation or something? Is opening a room possible?
I couldn't find any mention of it in the chat faqs, or anywhere, and I tried asking this question in the sandbox, but no one answered.
This should *really* be explained in the faqs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a privilege you gain with 100 reputation: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat-rooms, but there is no mention of this in the chat faq: http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq. Maybe a note should be added.

It should also be noted that all chat rooms are public and indexed by google. The only reason to make chat rooms is to not disturb those in other channels.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the chat window (chat links in on upper right) you get a message box

> Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat! You'll need 20 reputation
>   to talk here. This site is moderated by the community, so please be
>   respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users. And while
>   you're at it, check out the FAQ!

I don't know about opening new rooms though.